# Import and export db in graph

Tags: ios, swift, ios12, cosmicmind

thanks for the work done, graph is fantastic!

I would have a question is it possible to export and import all the database created?

Thank you

Comment: The question area is not to be used to thank someone. Nor can you expect that your follow-up question is directed to someone you may just have communicated with. A question should be self-sustained. Please read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you, as well to answer your question, you should be able to use the same exporting rules that CoreData will allow, as it is built on top of CoreData. We are going to add an import and export functionality at the API level, but that is coming up in early 2019.